# Get the max value of a column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following query:

```
select JdeAddressNo, LicenseNo, ExpirationDate, max(LicenseTypeId) licensetypeid
       from Licensing_DEV..License group by JdeAddressNo, LicenseNo, ExpirationDate
```

This query returns this result set:

```
Address#        License#        Expire date     LicenseTypeID
    30155   304157  2       015-08-31 00:00:00.000      2
    30155   PB0020052   2014-07-31 00:00:00.000     6
    30162   0000000115  2016-01-31 00:00:00.000     2
    30162   115         2014-01-31 00:00:00.000     3
    30162   PR0205559   2014-04-30 00:00:00.000     6
    30171   10CW00029700    2014-09-30 00:00:00.000     3
```

As you can see, there are duplicate rows returned for certain address numbers. What I need is to eliminate the dupes based on the license type ID. I want to only return the rows with the highest licensetypeID. So, for address number 30155, the row with license type ID of 6 should only be returned. Can some assist me in this? Thank you.

Comment: Your problem is that you are pulling down too many columns.  Once you create a unique record (which, have unique columns will do), it creates a new search for the MAX value.  You may need to do a subSELECT on the max values, so you only grab the last one it finds.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Row_number()` with `Partition by clause`

```
select * from
(
select *,rn=row_number()over(partition by Address# order by LicenseTypeID desc) from table
)x
where x.rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you the results you are looking for:

```
select L1.JdeAddressNo, L1.LicenseNo, L1.ExpirationDate, L1.LicenseTypeId 
from Licensing_DEV..License L1
INNER JOIN (SELECT JdeAddressNo, max(LicenseTypeId) as maxlicensetypeid
FROM Licensing_DEV..License 
GROUP BY JdeAddressNo
) L2 ON
L1.JdeAddressNo = L2.JdeAddressNo AND
L1.LicenseTypeId = l2.maxlicensetypeid
```